# Yii adding an Admin

Tags: authentication, yii, admin

I've been following the instructions here (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth) to add DB based authorization and users with Yii.  I can log in with a user defined in the user table, but i cannot log in as an admin.  I can see 1 row in my authassignment table with itemname 'admin' with a key to user id 1 - which is the user im using to log in.

My authManager looks like this:

```
'authManager'=>array(
    'class'=>'CDbAuthManager',
    'connectionID'=>'db',
    'defaultRoles'=>array('authenticated', 'admin'),
),
```

And the access rules for the particular controller im using are:

```
 public function accessRules() {
        return array(
            array('allow', // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions' => array('index', 'view'),
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions' => array('admin', 'delete','create', 'update'),
                'users' => array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny', // deny all users
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

Attempting to use the 'admin' action results in a 403 error.  I can't seem to get around this.  Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
So knowing that the bizrule for the admin authitem is `return Yii::app()->user->name === "admin";`, I changed the username of the user to 'admin' and it of course worked.  What do I need to change the bizrule to to let anyway who is an admin in the authassignment table log in as a admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `roles` in the accessRules, see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#access-control-filter and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAccessRule#roles-detail

```
class PostController extends CController
{
    ......
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',
                'actions'=>array('admin'),
                'roles'=>array('admin'),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. So the 'users' => array('admin'), part in the accessRules() is what is says it is, a list of allowed usernames, correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. There are also several other criterias, eg. `ips` or `expression`.